# contenteditable div "outdent"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable

I have a `contenteditable div` and use `execCommand("indent")` for the <kbd>tab</kbd> key. I discovered that it wraps the tabbed text inside a `blockquote` element, and when I hit <kbd>backspace</kbd> it doesn't remove the `blockquote` but it just goes to the previous line. Is there some sort of "outdent" command that I can use to remove the `blockquote` element? ([**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cKCEF/1/); note: I also discovered that when I hit <kbd>enter</kbd> it just wraps the following text in a `div` tag. Can this be avoided? I'd rather have it add a `<br>` element but no browsers support the `insertBrOnReturn` command.)

Any help would be much appreciated.

HTML

```
<div class="myClass"></div>
```

Javascript

```
$(".myClass").prop("contenteditable", true);

$(".myClass").on("keydown", function(e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if( keyCode === 9 ) {
        document.execCommand("indent", true, null);
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: Why not posting code here???

Comment: @A.Wolff I feel my above explanation warrants not posting code here. The only reason I included a JSFiddle is so that people who might be able to help me can play with it themselves conveniently. If I were to explain _and_ post my code, it would be a bit redundant. It's just basic code. I try to be concise as possible. Feel free to edit.

Comment: If `$(".myClass").prop("contenteditable", true);` works then I'm surprised: the property is `contentEditable` (note upper-case 'E'). Also, to be really pedantic, the value for `contentEditable` should be a string rather than a Boolean but Booleans do work in every browser I've tried.

Comment: @TimDown not in jQuery. The jQuery `prop` method _can_ accept a boolean then sets it accordingly. See [here](http://api.jquery.com/prop/). As for the lowercase "e", it does work for me in Chrome, IE, and Firefox (all latest) although I have yet to check it in Opera or Safari.

Comment: Also in every other example I've seen, it uses a lowercase e.

Comment: The attribute is `contenteditable`. The corresponding property is `contentEditable`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.contentEditable. Checking the jQuery source, I see that it does correct `contenteditable` to `contentEditable` when passed to `prop()`, which explains why it works. The pedantic point about Booleans still stands though: `prop()` does not change a `true` or `false` contenteditable value. As mentioned, it's not really that important since a Boolean value does work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is an "outdent" command. I have updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cKCEF/2/). Keep in mind that different browsers have different support for `contentEditable`. In Chrome the backspace will outdent your `contentEditable` by default, while in IE it wouldn't.

Comment: Okay, I [updated](http://jsfiddle.net/cKCEF/3/) that fiddle and removed `e.preventDefault()` and added `else if(keyCode === 8)` to detect [backspace] only. I still want the text to be deleted, _then_ the `outdent` to happen. Right now it's outdenting first, _then_ deleting text. Any way to reverse that?

Comment: Try changing from keyDown to keyPress.

Comment: That goes back to my original problem where it just goes to the previous line, no outdent. Using Chrome 32 on Windows 8.

Comment: Same as before. :( Shall we move this to chat?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45730/discussion-between-jace-cotton-and-konstantin-d-infragistics)